# Annotation Processor does not get triggered automatically?

Tags: java, android, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm trying to do annotation processing in android.
My Processor:-

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS) 
public @interface FirstAnotation {
     int rollno();
}
```

My example Model class:-

```
@FirstAnotation(rollno = 20120)
public class Model {
    String name;
}
```

Everytime when I change the rollno in Model class ,I have to rebuild the project again in order to reflect the changes in my generated class.

**Why is this happening ?**
 
If we have to rebuild the project again and again then how does **butterknife** works?